# Media Query CSS3 doesn't work for max-width: 420px

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I wanna make my website responsive and all sizes correctly work, but the problem is when the screen is <420px they use the media query 992px information, not the 420px why ? 
the problem is all classes work correctly in 420px but in this class, they take the 992px

```css
@media (max-width: 420px) {
  div.test {
    width: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container test">
  <img src="img/img.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Where is your HTML code?

Comment: The order of your media queries will determine which is applied. If you're calling a max 992px after max 420px, that one will be applied.

Comment: @DrewKennedy Thanks a loooot

Comment: @sayousayou you can also make your queries more specific by using an and operator (a>b and c<b) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#Logical_operators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're calling a `max-width:992px` media query after your `max-width:420px` media query is defined. Keep in mind CSS is compiled top-down, and your logic needs to accommodate this. Instead, consider your media query order:

```
@media (max-width:992px) {
    ...
}

@media (max-width:420px) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to build the site "mobile first", meaning the default values are for the mobile version, and then you can override width definitions using media queries.

So if you want 200px on 420px width, and 400px on 992px width, you should do something like:

```
.test {
  width: 200px;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .test {
    width: 400px;
  }
}
```

Always use `min-width` and always start with the small resolution and override with bigger resolutions.